Was the universe created from a supermassive black hole?
Was the universe actually created from a supermassive black hole in another universe rather than simply the Big Bang? If so, would this explain how other universes are created?
It's recently been proposed that blackholes are actually frozen stars, the research pointing towards this makes a lot of sense. Black holes are a key part of our universe, almost every large galaxy in our universe has a supermassive one at its centre. We know that information cannot be destroyed and that supermassive black holes emit jets of plasma.

More on Big Bang & black holes.

See the Cosmological natural selection hypothesis (also called the fecund universes) proposed by Lee Smolin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_natural_selection

Was the universe actually created from a supermassive black hole in another universe ?
Physics is an empirical science. To answer your question within the realm of physics we would have to know how to find physical evidence that either supports your hypothesis or contradicts it. And before anyone can do that, you would have to provide more details on exactly how our universe could have been created from a supermassive black hole in another universe.
